# GORM hibernate criteria query via dynamic association

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have a GORM domain object that has an association to another object via two different columns. I'm trying to get some data via a couple nested joins. Rather than joining twice and having the number of rows returned increase exponentially, I decided to split the query in two.

Is there a way to dynamically indicate the column that you are querying against? In other words, is it possible to take this bit of code...

```
Set<Template> templates = new HashSet<Template>()
templates.addAll(Template.createCriteria().list {
  eq 'isActive',true
  eq 'allowCustomerRequest',true
  buyer {
    companyUsers {
      eq 'userId',userId
    }
  }
})
templates.addAll(Template.createCriteria().list {
  eq 'isActive',true
  eq 'allowCustomerRequest',true
  seller {
    companyUsers {
      eq 'userId',userId
    }
  }
})
```

and shorten it to something like this

```
Set<Template> templates = new HashSet<Template>()
['buyer','seller'].each{ who ->
  templates.addAll(Template.createCriteria().list {
    eq 'isActive',true
    eq 'allowCustomerRequest',true
    who {
      companyUsers {
        eq 'userId',userId
      }
    }
  })
}
```

**EDIT**
As indicated by @dmahapatro it is possible to do this in a single query, but the way I'm thinking it would be done increases the number of rows by quite a bit. Here's an example of doing the multiple joins...

```
Set<Template> templates = new HashSet<Template>()
templates.addAll(Template.createCriteria().listDistinct {
  eq 'isActive',true
  eq 'allowCustomerRequest',true
  or{
    buyer {
      companyUsers {
        eq 'userId',userId
      }
    }
    seller {
      companyUsers {
        eq 'userId',userId
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Doing a LEFT JOIN on both `buyer` and `seller` in a single criteria query should solve the purpose, right?

Comment: @dmahapatro yes, I can do this in a single criteria but it will exponentially increase the number of rows returned. The duplicates can be filtered out via listDistinct. But I got chastised a little by another dev who said that it took too long on his VPN connection. :P